# How to enlarge Safari's smart search bar?

Tags: safari, url

Is it possible to enlarge / to broaden the smart search bar as well as the suggestion box in Safari (>=15.5) when 'compact' tab layout is selected in the settings?

Some websites use pretty URLs to exactly show you where you are. For instance Gitlab or Github show you the project path in the URL so it can be very long. However in Safari it's not possible to make use of that information if you can't see it:

[image: image of smart searchbar]

Any ideas how to "hack" the UI of Safari? At least I haven't found a setting yet.

Comment: Safari > View > Customize Toolbar and drag the "flexible spaces" out of the current toolbar. I get a lot more URL that way, not sure if it is enough for your need but it is simple and easy to try...

Comment: @SteveChambers those "flexible spaces" aren't available in the "compact" tab layout ( https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/ibrw1045/mac ) .

Comment: @ThomasSteinbach where is it written?